# HTML static bar on top covers the link to the section

Tags: html

I have a static horizontal bar on the top of the website, this height of the bar is 100px. In the body of the html I have something like:

```
<a name="photo-section"></a>
```

So I can recall that section from my website www.domain.com/#photo-section
The problem is that the bar covers part (100px) of the photo section because it is static; is there some solution to this? I added a white div on the top but it looks very bad on the actual website.

You can see the problem when you click on the nav link "photo" [in here](http://www.bootply.com/lN6EwpqyyK)

Thanks

Comment: can you share more information? Maybe a link to a fiddle/actual site? Some css code being used?

Comment: Post your HTML layout.

Comment: try adding `margin-top` for the top div in body. If there was a fiddle it would be easy to rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You can try this by adding a little CSS:

```
<a href="#photo-section">Jump to Photo Section</a>

[....]
<a name="photo-section" style="display: block; padding-top: 100px;">Photo Section</a>
```

**Solution 2:** Or using jQuery or whatever javascript-like:

```
<a name="photo-section" id="photo-section">Photo Section</a>
```

and then trigger the animations by

```
<script>
function scrollBonus(id) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($(id).scrollTop() + 100) + 'px'}, 300);
}
</script>
```

And if you want to trigger it even if the visitors click your link from another page:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
          scrollBonus(window.location.hash);
     });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Thinh Nguyen, the first solution "works" I tried before posting here but the problem is it leaves a huge(100px)  space on the website; i want to avoid that. And using javascript may do the work but sometimes there is no link on the website but the #photo is in another page, therefore I should capture every request and check if there is a # etc, it becomes a bit messy. Another solution? Thanks

Comment: @Gonzalo see my edited answer to see if it helps. a little more javascript should do this. at this point I didn't come up with any other solution rather than this.